# air conditioner pipe pvc glue

Tags: plumbing, air-conditioning, pvc

I recently bought a new air condition. The guy who came to install it in my bedroom used PVC glue to joint two pipes the one of the air condition with the outside one(instead he could use something else), ..and this pipe get the air inside and water outside.
The first 24 hours there was a toxic smell of the glue even if it was off. I had the windows opened for hours and after I closed them , you could smell again the glue. Now(after a week) you can't smell anything except if you are under the air condition which it has a strange smell (maybe it is the air, when you turn it on), I can't understand if it smells glue or because the air condition is new.
Is now the air condition good for use?
I am worried if the smell is still in the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the fan on for a week and all the solvents in the glue should out gass in this time, most water pipes are glued and charged with water within 24 hours and in a day or 2 the solvents are gone and don't show up in testing, have been through this several times. A total pain in my back side. After 36 hours the levels were not dectable on a MSA or RGA that the owner who insisted on CPVC when I suggested copper. I think his total bill on the 2 samples for each test was several hundred each + the cost of a technician taking the samples... Give it a day or 2 with the fan on and I believe you will find the same.

Comment: +Ed for a gentlemanly response.